# how to set a path while saving image with jsp/servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

signup.jsp: here am not able to set path to save my uploaded image inside a folder????thanks in advance..!!everything is fine and evrything is working properyly but image path is showing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<base href="<%=basePath%>">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Interactive Demos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/


</head>

<body>
<header>
<jsp:include page="header1.jsp"/>


</header>
<!--start mainwrap-->
<div id="mainwrap">

<!--start midwrap-->
<div id="midwrap">

<table style="width:100%; border:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:0px;">
  <!-- <tr>
    <td style="width:74%; vertical-align:top;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width:26%; ">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr> -->

   <h1 style="padding-top:6px; font-family: Palatino Linotype;  font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; color:#476aba; border-bottom:2px solid #476aba">Registration</h1>

  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
    <div class="lf" style="width:500px; margin-left: 240px;">
    <!-- <div style="font-size: 25px"> -->

   <!--  </div> -->
    <div class="tp-btm">

    <div style="border-radius:7px; border:1px solid black; background-color: #e7ebf5; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;">

    <form name = "frmRegistration"  id="frmRegistration"  onsubmit="submitAlbum()" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table style="width:100%; text-align:center; border:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:0px; text-align:center;">




  <tr>
    <td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height:40; text-align:left;" class="text">E-mail :<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="25" required="required" onmouseout=""  placeholder="Eg: admin@bdisys.com"  pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" /></td>
  </tr>





  <tr>
    <td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height: 40" class="text"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; padding-right: 25px;"><input type="checkbox" name="imgstatus" id="imgstatus" onclick="showFileUpload();">Click Here To Set Default Image </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height: 40" class="text">Upload Image :<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<input type="hidden" value="images/blogs.png" name="defaultimg" id="defaultimg"> </td>
    <td style="text-align: center; padding-left: 50px;"><input type="file" name="datafile" id="datafile" size="42" required="required"
                            onchange="checkFilesExtention(this);" accept='image/png,image/jpg,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/bmp,image/x-eps'>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height:32;" class="text">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:50px; padding-top:20px;"><input type="image"  class="ab" src="images/submiit.png"/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>

</div>
    </div>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:5;" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<!--end midwrap-->
</div>
<!--end mainwrap-->

<footer>
<jsp:include page="footer1.jsp"/>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Servlet.java : i want to know how to set this path ???thanks in advance for any help!!

```
public class signUpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String webTempPath;
    private String filename;

//  String server_url="http://localhost:8080/BDI Systems/";
    private static Properties properties;

    private static String filePath = MailSenderDAO.class.getResource("").getPath().replaceAll("%20", " ");
static {
try {
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(filePath + "/mail.config"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
//  ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void init(){
     webTempPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"images/";
    }

    public signUpServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session =request.getSession();
        UserDao userDao=new UserDaoImpl();
        System.out.println("Inside SignUp Servlet===============");
        String formIdentity=request.getParameter("formidentity");//activateaccount
        System.out.println("FormIdentity================"+formIdentity);

        if(formIdentity.equalsIgnoreCase("doRegistration"))
        {
//          System.out.println("Inside doRegistration===================="+properties.getProperty("server_url"));

            String checkboxStatus=request.getParameter("checkboxStatus");
             System.out.println("status...."+checkboxStatus);
             MultipartRequest mpr = null;
             Throwable e;
            if(checkboxStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
            {
                     mpr=new MultipartRequest(request,webTempPath,5*1024*1024,new MnthFileRenamePolicy());
                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    System.out.println("inside add details..");
                 try{


                          System.out.println("in datafile con of  servlet...");

                          this.filename=mpr.getFilesystemName("datafile");


                          File srcFile=new File(webTempPath+this.filename); 
                          System.out.println("  web temp=="+webTempPath);
                          System.out.println("image path==="+webTempPath+this.filename);

                          mpr.copyFile(srcFile, new File(webTempPath+this.filename));
                          String imgpath="images/"+this.filename;
                          System.out.println("image is=="+imgpath);
                          System.out.println("After file of  servlet...");

                          User user=new User();
                          user.setFirstName(mpr.getParameter("fname"));
                          user.setLastName(mpr.getParameter("lname"));
                          user.setEmail(mpr.getParameter("email"));
                          user.setDesc(mpr.getParameter("desc"));
                          user.setProfession(mpr.getParameter("profession"));
                          user.setDateofbirth(mpr.getParameter("dob"));
                          user.setLocation(mpr.getParameter("location"));
                          user.setProjects(mpr.getParameter("myprojects"));
                          user.setHobbies(mpr.getParameter("myhobbies")); 
                          user.setImagePath(imgpath);

                          user.setPassword(SecurityManager.asyEncrypt(mpr.getParameter("password")));
                          user.setUserStatus(Status.UNBLOCKED);
                          user.setUserType(UserType.NORMAL);
                          user.setCreatedOn(new Date());



                           User createduser=userDao.createUser(user);
                           System.out.println("hi this is temp..."+temp);
                           if(createduser==null){
                              System.out.println("hi this is ...");
                              response.sendRedirect("Registration?status=exist");
                       }


                    }


                    catch(Exception e1){
                              e1.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        userDao.closeSession();
                    }
                }

                 else 
                 if (checkboxStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                 {

                     System.out.println("in datafile con of  servlet...");

                    try{

                              User user=new User();
                              user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("fname"));
                              user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lname"));
                              user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
                              user.setDesc(request.getParameter("desc"));
                              user.setProfession(request.getParameter("profession"));
                              user.setDateofbirth(request.getParameter("dob"));
                              user.setLocation(request.getParameter("location"));
                              user.setProjects(request.getParameter("myprojects"));
                              user.setHobbies(request.getParameter("myhobbies"));
                              user.setImagePath(request.getParameter("defaultimg"));
                              user.setPassword(SecurityManager.asyEncrypt(request.getParameter("password")));
                              user.setUserStatus(Status.UNBLOCKED);
                              user.setUserType(UserType.NORMAL);
                              user.setCreatedOn(new Date());
                              System.out.println("in try con of  servlet...");




                              User createduser=userDao.createUser(user);
                              if(createduser==null){
                                 response.sendRedirect("Registration?status=exist");
                              }



                        }   
                    catch(Exception e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();

                    }finally{
                        userDao.closeSession();
                    }
                 }

        }

}
```

Comment: Too much of code to go through. Since everything is working except for your path, can you trim down code to what is related? Please specify if there is any error, and what is expected path, and what path is being shown.

Comment: hi sudarshan .ya i trimed it.  the problem is only with the path to be specified...when i upload an image it is not getting saved inside the mentioned folder!! it is showing some garbage path inside database like   eg:images/Resumejjndfvnfvdlvdfsv;ldfvldsldsfvl.png

Comment: Oops. I shouldn't have asked to trim down code. Code for how and where are you setting 'webTempPath' and 'filename' is important. Sorry about that. Without knowing how path's are set, it's difficult to analyse.

Comment: sudarshan i had posted the code once again just check it once and thanks for any help!!!

Comment: its hsowing in this way in database when it is saved but the image is not getting saved inside folder... images/Resume_PFSaf8tQz9g0-1392793613362.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define name of the directory where uploaded images will be saved, relative to
the web application directory:

```
private static final String SAVE_DIRECTORY = "images";
```

Then define save path and create the directory if it does not exists:

```
String absolutePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIRECTORY;

File imageSaveDirectory = new File(savePath);
if (!imageSaveDirectory.exists()) {
    imageSaveDirectory.mkdir();
}
```